# PancakeSwapV2 router "getAmountsOut" function returns wrong value

Tags: contract-invocation, pancakeswap, nethereum, binance-smart-chain, c#

I'm struggling with "getAmountsOut" function, which works kinda fine for BNB/CAKE or CAKE/BNB. But it in some cases it just returns straight wrong values.

Code:

```
public async Task<decimal> GetAmountsOut(string token0, string token1, decimal wbnbAmountToSpend)
{
    string formattedValue = wbnbAmountToSpend.ToString("0.####");
    decimal result = decimal.Parse(formattedValue);
    var amountsOut = await _pancakeSwapV2Router.GetFunction("getAmountsOut").CallAsync<List<BigInteger>>(
        Web3.Convert.ToWei(result), new[] { token0, token1 });
    return Web3.Convert.FromWei(amountsOut[1]);
}
```

Method itself returns 0.00000000119623015M amount of NVTN for 0.003 BNB while on exchange I get normal value:
[image]
Same goes for vice-versa:

[image]

While in code for NVTN/BNB with same amount of 0.003 it returns: 739.338138502378758758M

Can you see the mistake? Maybe this is decimals/conversion problems?

UPD: Yea, this seems to be a problem with decimals, but I don't understand why it happens in first place if both tokens are 9 decimals.
Also, why this doesn't happen with BNB/CAKE for example?